# Enable NuGet restore when publishing programmatically using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation

Tags: c#, msbuild

I'm trying to publish a web application with below code which uses Microsoft.Build.Evaluation libraries. However below execution fails for a project with error message mentioning to enable NuGet restore. The provided link in error message is not valid since it shows how to enable NuGet restore in Visual Studio IDE.

Please let me know how to enable NuGet when programmatically publishing a web app with Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.

```
Build FAILED.

C:\x\Dnn.Platform-development\DNN Platform\DotNetNuke.Web\DotNetNuke.Web.csproj(419,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer.Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\..\..\Evoq.Content\\.nuget\NuGet.targets.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

**The source code used to publish the web application:**

```
using B = Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;
using Microsoft.Build.Logging;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebPublisherTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static private readonly string RootTempFolder = @"C:\TST";
        static private readonly string PublishDropFolderName = "PublishDrop";
        static private readonly string ToolVersion = "12.0";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string projectFilePath = @"C:\x\Dnn.Platform-development\DNN Platform\Admin Modules\Dnn.Modules.Console\Dnn.Modules.Console.csproj";
            string tempLocation = Path.Combine(RootTempFolder, Path.GetRandomFileName());
            string publishDrop = Path.Combine(tempLocation, PublishDropFolderName);

            var globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Configuration", "Debug" },
                    { "OutputPath", publishDrop },
                    { "WebPublishMethod", "FileSystem" }
                };

            ConsoleLogger logger = new ConsoleLogger(verbosity: LoggerVerbosity.Normal);

            B.Project p = new B.Project(projectFilePath, globalProperty, ToolVersion);
            p.Build(new List<ILogger>() { logger });
        }
    }
}
```